# How can I echo the amount of bytes removed from an rm -rf?

Tags: macos, bash

I have an alias

```
alias binobj="find . -iname "bin" -o -iname "obj" | xargs rm -rf"
```

That I use when my disk is almost full. This deletes the folders "bin" and "obj", recursively searching from the current folder.

I would like to know how I can know the total sum of all deleted files. I have looked into placing an echo in between the 2 commands through a pipe, but then the `xargs` won't receive the files to delete.

I am on a mac, but I'm not shy of adding packages. I just don't want to put this in another file (this is my `.bash_profile`), as this one syncs with all my other macs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to be very careful doing a recursive find for `bin` and `obj`... for example, you might accidentally pop off important files or directories (e.g: `.../.hg/store/data/obj`) which would not be a good idea.

Where at all possible, you want to be as precise as you can be. If you're trying to remove directories, then specify `-type d` so that you don't accidentally match a file / symlink / etc...

Additionally, this is large enough that it would benefit being a set of functions for readability / maintainability.

This set of functions (and finally a pipeline that can be aliased / put into a function) will remove all `bin` and `obj` directories that are next to a file called `makefile` (all case insensitive).
The total bytes will be written to `stderr` using the shy `numfmt` to get output such as "`9.1MB`"

```bsh
function getMakefiles {
    find . -type f -iname makefile
}

function getBinObjDirsNear {
    while read NEAR; do
        find $(dirname ${NEAR}) -type d -maxdepth 1 \( -iname bin -o -iname obj \)
    done
}

function calcTotal {
    TOTAL=0
    while read ENT; do
        TOTAL=$(( TOTAL + $(du -bc ${ENT} | tail -n 1 | cut -f 1) ))
        echo ${ENT}
    done
    numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B --format="%f" ${TOTAL} >&2
}

getMakefiles | getBinObjDirsNear | calcTotal | xargs -d '\n' rm -rf
```

Comment: It is a really good idea to check for a makefile next to the obj bin folders to ensure nothing can be broken. I have executed the command before, but it's probably a good idea to stop doing that. I can't use makefile to check for though, but I can use the solution & project files where the folders will be next to.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply compute the size before removing the folders :

`alias binobj="du -sc bin/ obj/ | grep total ; find . -iname "bin" -o -iname "obj" | xargs rm -rf"`

The command will prompt you the added size in bytes of the `bin` + `obj` directories from the current directory; then execute to delete.

**Edit**: According to comment : the `bin` and `obj` should be found recursively :

Without putting much time to find a elegant solution, I would log the size of each directory before removing it, and compute them after the cleaning is complete.
A dirty one liner could be :

`find . -iname "bin" -o -iname "obj" | xargs -I % sh -c "du -sb % >> /tmp/delreport.log; rm -rf %"; awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}' /tmp/delreport.log && rm /tmp/delreport.log`

- `| xargs -I % sh -c "..."` : allows you to put multiple commands with the \% parameter
- `du -sb` : will log you the size of the repository which will be removed
- `awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'` : sum up all the size in the first column of the report

Comment: I think it's nearly good, but the du is not recursive, which is important as I sometimes run it from my projects folder to clean up all my projects.

Comment: @user1009013 I added a some information according to you need of recursively finding the directories